# How to programmatically refresh an access token (JWT) when using a separate auth server?

Tags: node.js, jwt, express-jwt

I'd like to use JWTs for user authorization. My intention is use an auth server and an app server to keep them separate. This way my auth server will be the only JWT issuing server as well as the only server w/login and sign up logic.

I have a working proof of concept in node.js, however I've recently run into an issue - how do I refresh a user's access token from an app server if my auth server is separate (on a different IP address)?

What I'm doing now:

1. each client sends via secure, httponly cookies his/her access-token and refresh-token
2. I then use middleware to check the validity of a user's access-token
3. if the access-token is valid, all is well, but if it fails, I need to present the user's refresh-token to the auth server, to get a new access token (this is where I'm stuck)

What's the best way to do this?

Should I make a remote HTTPS request from middleware to get a new access-token?

I don't see another way if I'm using a remote server.